# how to handle ssl certificate expiration in android?

Tags: android, ssl-certificate, android-webservice

i have an application with pinned SSL certificates and these certificates will store in android keystore file and released the apk to playstore. Now the certificate inside the keystore has expired, so is there a way to update the certificate with out releasing a new build to play store?